# game maker place_meeting multiple objects

Tags: game-maker

I am working on a simple game that contains two objects the player and the ground, and I used place_meeting to make the player walk on the ground object and it works fine but when I try to add another object to make the player walk on it, it didn't work and the game freeze, here is my code:

```
// vertical collision
if place_meeting(x,y+vsp,ground1) or place_meeting(x,y+vsp,ground2)
{
while ((!place_meeting(x,y+sign(vsp),ground1 )) or (!place_meeting(x,y+sign(vsp),oground1=2 )))

 y+=sign(vsp);

    if (sign(vsp) ==1)
    {
    grounded = 1;
    }

    vsp =0;

 }
else
{
grounded = 0;
}
y+= vsp;
```

Comment: Ofc the game will freeze: when you touch the ground it will never get out of the while loop. Use an if statement.

Answer (score 4):

You will get into all sorts of problems with complex if statements. Here is the solution I use, and it works for any number of grounds.

1. Define an object `obj_ground`. Put no code in this object, and do not define a sprite.
2. Create your two types ground objects.
3. For each of your ground objects, define `obj_ground` as their parent. This means that every time you reference `obj_ground`, you check both! Look up [parent and child](https://docs.yoyogames.com/source/dadiospice/001_advanced%20use/more%20about%20objects/parents.html) in the user manual, it is one of the tools that makes GameMaker so good.

Answer (score 0):

I am to understand that **ground1** and **ground2** are your 2 types of walkable objects.

So, on line 3 of your code, in your while loop, the object in your last check is incorrect. It shoud be **(!place_meeting(x,y+sign(vsp),ground2 ))**

```
while ((!place_meeting(x,y+sign(vsp),ground1 )) or (!place_meeting(x,y+sign(vsp),ground2 )))
```

Try that.

Answer (score 0):

Here's mine

```
//Horizontal Collision
if (place_meeting(x+hspeed,y,obj_wall))
{
    while(!place_meeting(x+sign(hspeed),y,obj_wall))
    {
        x += sign(hspeed);
    }
    hspeed = 0;
}
x += hspeed;

//Vertical Collision
if (place_meeting(x,y+vspeed,obj_wall))
{
    while(!place_meeting(x,y+sign(vspeed),obj_wall))
    {
        y += sign(vspeed);
    }
    vspeed = 0;
}
y += vspeed;
```